# How to get an element that was appended by before method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

the source example is kind of this

```
// block with caption
var caption_block = "<div class='caption-block'><h1>"+ options.title + "</h1><div class='pages'><a href='/' id='left_pg'></a><div id='counter'>"+ (i+1)+'/'+(elms+1)+"</div><a href='/' id='right_pg'></a></div></div>";

// put the elemnt with caption into the DOM
$('ul.slider').before(caption_block);

// by click in #counter TEST
$('a').bind('click',function(){

 $('#slider').find('#counter').text(" TEST ");

});
```

Unluck, but it's don't do anything at all.

The script can't find a `div#counter`. How to get it?

the html looks like

```
<div id="slider"><ul class="slider" /></div>
```

Comment: I am even doesn't know which anwser is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're using it, `before` is adding `ul.slider` as a sibling to the caption block containing `div#counter`. You could select for slider by checking their mutual parent for it:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('#slider').parent().find('#counter').text(" TEST ");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, something was wrong in my script maybe, now it's works perfectly!

Comment: @Vega makes a good point (thanks, mate!), but be careful both with using `id` selectors and the document-level match if you plan to use this approach more than once on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

With previous

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $('#slider').prev('div').find('#counter').text(" TEST ");
});
```

or use parent of slider

```
$('a').click(function(){

     $('#slider').parent.find('#counter').text(" TEST ");
});
```

Directly with id

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $('#counter').text(" TEST ");
});
```

Comment: sorry, I am typing it and was out look.

Answer (score 1):

Just write `$('#counter').text(" TEST ")`

also I think you need bind you link tag like below,

```
$('a', $('ul.slider')).click (function () {
    $('#counter').text(" TEST ")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're referencing slider by class name `.slider`, later you reference it by id `#slider`.

Second, you dont' have an anchor with id 'a' `#a`, you probably want to use `$('a')` to reference the anchor element.

Third, your selector is looking for `#counter` inside of slider, which it's not a child of.  It was inserted before slider, not as a child.

See this fiddle for some working code http://jsfiddle.net/DyexP/2/

```
<ul id="slider" class="slider">ul</ul>​

var i = 1;
var elms = 10;
var options = {};
options.title = "title";

// block with caption
var caption_block = "<div class='caption-block'><h1>"+ options.title + "</h1><div class='pages'><a href='/' id='left_pg'></a><div id='counter'>"+ (i+1)+'/'+(elms+1)+"</div><a href='#' id='right_pg'>click me</a></div></div>";

// put the elemnt with caption into the DOM
$('ul.slider').before(caption_block);

// by click in #counter TEST
$('a').click(function(){
     $('#slider').parent().find('#counter').text(" TEST ");
});​
```